# Troubles with gitlab scraping via golang

Tags: multithreading, go, web-scraping, gitlab

I'm newbie in programming and I need help. Trying to write gitlab scraper on golang. 
Something goes wrong when i'm trying to get information about projects in multithreading mode.

Here is the code:

```
func (g *Gitlab) getAPIResponce(url string, structure interface{}) error {
    responce, responce_error := http.Get(url)
    if responce_error != nil {
        return responce_error
    }
    ret, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(responce.Body)
    if string(ret) != "[]" {
        err := json.Unmarshal(ret, structure)
        return err
    }
    return errors.New(error_emptypage)
}

...

func (g *Gitlab) GetProjects() {
    projects_chan := make(chan Project, g.LatestProjectID) 
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup                           
    queue := make(chan struct{}, 50)                                      
    for i := g.LatestProjectID; i > 0; i-- {               
        url := g.BaseURL + projects_url + "/" + strconv.Itoa(i) + g.Token
        waitGroup.Add(1)
        go func(url string, channel chan Project) {
            queue <- struct{}{}
            defer waitGroup.Done()

            var oneProject Project
            err := g.getAPIResponce(url, &oneProject)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
            }

            fmt.Printf(".")
            channel <- oneProject
            <-queue
        }(url, projects_chan)
    }

    go func() {
        waitGroup.Wait()
        close(projects_chan)
    }()

    for project := range projects_chan {
        if project.ID != 0 {
            g.Projects = append(g.Projects, project)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
$ ./gitlab-auditor 
latest project = 1532
Gathering projects...
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/563&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/558&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
..Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/531&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/571&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
.Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/570&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
..Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/467&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
Get https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/573&private_token=SeCrEt_ToKeN: unexpected EOF
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
```

Every time it's different projects, but it's id is around 550.

When I'm trying to curl links from output, i'm getting normal JSON. When I'm trying to run this code with `queue := make(chan struct{}, 1)` (in single thread) - everything is fine.

What can it be?

Comment: Try to limit number of simultaneous connections.

Comment: I'm trying to do it here: `queue := make(chan struct{}, N)` (N = number of connection), and it partially helps, but i'm loosing performance. Does it a problem of gitlab, golang or my computer?

Comment: I guess 50 is too much. There could be some sort of DDoS protection which limits number of connections. Try to make less, say 5 or 10.

Comment: looks like you were right, this works perfectly(but slowly - 1500+ projects, 42 seconds):

`projects_chan := make(chan Project, 2)`
and
`queue := make(chan struct{}, 3)`

Comment: You can find optimal number or use some proxies so your requests would look like being from  different sources.

Comment: Make sure to inspect the http response code.  Gitlab is probably telling you exactly why your calls are failing, but your code is ignoring it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say this not a very clear way to achieve concurrency.
what seems to be happening here is

- you create a buffered channel that has a size of 50.
- then you fire up 1532 goroutines
- the first 50 of them enqueue themselves and start processing. by the time they <-queue and free up somespace a random one from the next manages to get on the queue.
- as people say in the comments most certainly you hit some limits around the time it the blast has made it around id 550. Then gitlab's API is angry at you and rate limits.
- then another goroutine is fired that will close the channel to notify the main goroutine
- the main goroutine reads messages.

the talk [go concurrency patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs)
as well as this blog post [concurrency in go](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) might help.
personally i rarely use buffered channels. for your problem i would go like:

- define a number of workers
- have the main goroutine fire up the workers with a func listening on a channel of ints , doing the api call, writing to a channel of projects
- have the main goroutine send to a channel of ints the project number to be fetched and read from the channel of projects.

  - maybe ratelimit by firing a ticker and have main read from it before it sends the next request?
- main closes the number channel to notify the others to die.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and especially thanks for link to "go concurrency patterns". I already solved this problem by limiting the amount of threads and tuning Gitlab according the  Eugene Lisitsky's answer